# Needed help in converting this SQL query to Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

```
INSERT INTO customer_hobbies(cust_id,hobby_id)
VALUES(913,4)
SELECT c.cust_id FROM customers c
JOIN customer_hobbies ch
ON ch.cust_id = c.cust_id;
```

Now, both `cust_id,hobby_id` are foreign keys in `customer_hobbies` table and cust_id is a primary key in customers table.

If I could get an Entity Framework Query to store both id's in `customer_hobbies` table it would help me abundantly.

Thank You.

Comment: What are ```913``` and ```4```? Also, when you run the select, you're getting only one column (```c.cust_id```). Is this OK?

Comment: 913 = cust_id(foreign key in CUSTOMER_HOBBIES table;primary key in CUSTOMERS table) and 4 = hobby_id(foreign key in CUSTOMER_HOBBIES table;primary key in HOBBIES table). When I select I want to get only one column yes i.e (c.cust_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first query, you can use:

```cs
// INSERT INTO customer_hobbies(cust_id,hobby_id)
// VALUES(913,4)
db.CustomerHobbies.AddObject(new CustomerHobbies { CustID = 913, HobbyID = 4 });
db.SaveChanges();
```

(the exact property names depend on the entity framework conversion configuration)

For the second query, since you're not using any field from customer_hobbies, you can just query customers.

Even if you want to get the column `c.cust_id`, since that is also the join key, you can just query it from `customer_hobbies`.

For example:

```cs
var ch = db.CustomerHobbies.Where(/* some predicate */).First();
var customerID = ch.CustID;
```

Comment: Thank You Juan for you time in considering my question. The above query is actually an INSERT-SELECT query like how we do in MYSQL. it is not two separate queries. Is it possible to do that in Entity Framework?